# Trying to pass jQuery event to module pattern function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, callback, module-pattern

I am trying the module pattern for the first time for a form that logs users in. I want to pass the submit event to the authenticate user function, but for some reason the authenticate user function does not run, the preventDefault() function I have in place for testing does not run and the form gets submitted anyways... Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or point me in the right direction? Thank you ahead of time!

Here is my initial code and approach:

```
var Login = (function(){
  var form;

  var init = function (formId) {
    form = formId;
    return form;
  }

  var authenticate = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return {
    init: init,
    authenticate: authenticate
  }
})();

$(function(){
  var mainLogin = Login.init( $("form#login-form") );
  mainLogin.submit( mainLogin.authenticate )
});
```

After getting feedback, I think I need the constructor pattern instead because I want to make this approach modular so it can work with any login form:

```
var Login = function(form){
  this.form = form;

  var authenticate = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return {
    form: form,
    authenticate: authenticate
  }
};

$(function(){
  var mainLogin = new Login($("form#login-form"));
  mainLogin.form.submit( mainLogin.authenticate );
});
```

Is this a better approach?

Comment: But why? Why have a function that just returns whatever you pass in, and `authenticate` is not the same as `authenticate_user`, those are two different things

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I left the authenticate-user in there by accident, I was toying around to get the code to work! And yes, I was thinking the init function can return the form so I can continue calling functions on it?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because `mainLogin` is clearly the form wrapped in jQuery, it's not the object that has the `authenticate` property

Comment: But really you've just written `$("#login-form").submit( function(e) { e.preventDefault() })` in the most complicated way possible.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. So now I've removed the return form in the init method. Basically what I'm trying to do is make a modular login system so that if we implement another place to log in, I can just replace the form with another form and everything else would work the same. Should I take a different approach to this?

Comment: Okay, so I think I need the constructor pattern instead. I say this because I want to make the login methods adaptable to any login form. Is this correct? I've edited my question to include my new approach.